# ms-access generate string in textbox based on form options

Tags: ms-access, vba

I want to generate a string in a text box based on values selected in my form. Also need to insert pre-defined text before and after some of the form options selected. Pre-defined text is in bold below. Want this to process with the on generate text on-click button and placed in the text box below the buttons. Already have the code for reset button working. See sample form below.

ex text: **Process** [entity.value] **and** [action.value] **then** [status.value] **use agreement** [agreement.value] **with eff date** [eff_date.value]........and so on.

[Sample Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ysqA.jpg)

Comment: You may have to provide a few examples of input and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you need is to build a sting based off of those values then what you are looking for is...

```
FinalTxt = "Process " & me.entity.value & _ 
           " and " & me.action.value & _
           " then " & me.status.value & _
           " use agreement " & me.agreement.value & _
           " with eff date " & me.eff_date.value

me.FinalTxtBox.value = FinalTxt
```

If you need to save the string to use it on another form I would consider creating a public variable for that string and updating that as well.

--Update

To keep the string from showing in the text box you would need to add in a little bit of logic.

```
FinalTxt = ""

If me.entity.value <> "" and me.action.value <> "" _
    and me.status.value <> "" and me.agreement.value <> "" _
    and me.eff_date.value <> "" Then

    FinalTxt = "Process " & me.entity.value & _ 
           " and " & me.action.value & _
           " then " & me.status.value & _
           " use agreement " & me.agreement.value & _
           " with eff date " & me.eff_date.value 

End If

me.FinalTxtBox.value = FinalTxt
```

Comment: The above code works exactly as I need it to thanks!

Comment: How would I insert a null value so that if a combo box is not selected  or value not entered then the string would not show?